# What does IE need for a drop down menu to remain on top of an iframe?

Tags: css

For example:
The following site looks ok in Firefox when the menu Massage Types is selected. The menu drops down in front of the iframe so it is still visible.

But in IE, the bottom of the menu gets hidden behind by the iframe.

http://transeeq.com/health/bq15b.html#

Comment: in IE7 i got the following error:
---------------------------
Windows Internet Explorer
---------------------------
Internet Explorer cannot open the Internet site http://transeeq.com/health/bq15b.html.
Operation aborted
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Answer (score 1):

IE6 developers "cheated" by using the operating system to render these elements instead of rendering them as browser controls. So these elements behave as if they are "outside" of the browser.

You can cover these up with an iframe, but the z-index of the iframe needs to be greater than that of the .

This problem comes up a lot with modal dialogs. To fix this, solution is to determine the position and dimensions of the  elements on the page, and to overlay them with an iframe pointing to a blank page before the modal dialog is shown, than removed when it is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include { z-index: 99; } to your dropdown style